# View, Edit, Add, Delete records with MySQLi

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I was following this [Tutorial][1] to create add new, edit existing and delete records from my database for school class information.

I can successfully delete records, but I cannot add new or edit existing.

When I select to edit a row the url updates e.g. `records.php?cid=2` but records.php opens with the title 'New Class' with none of the existing record information filled in.

**Edit**

I have updated the code ( removing the '?' syntax error) and the number of type varibles for the bind_param.

New records are now adding but still not sure with how to pass the check for $cid.

Thanks for the help and will definitely consider using Laravel in the future.

Comment: That's because your check for `$cid` never pass.

Comment: I'd strongly advise you to avoid tutorials like that and instead find a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that fits your style and needs. Building your own site from the ground up is a difficult exercise and you'll waste a lot of time painfully re-doing what a framework can do in minutes. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a good example of one that's quite beginner friendly, and the documentation includes an introduction that's a lot higher quality than most tutorials. Given the same amount of time, you'll be far more productive that way.

Comment: @tadman I think the frameworks especially `Laravel` is great but How about understanding what the framework is doing for me? is not worth it to put effort to learn the core language?

Comment: I honestly don't know why that tutorial uses `htmlentities()`. That's only for display purposes to safeguard against XSS attacks, and it stands at doing more harm than good. If that's their idea of *helping* to reduce a possible SQL injection, it's not working. A prepared statement alone is good enough.

Comment: You're also using more placeholders and variables than the number in `bind_param()`. That alone should have thrown you an error but you failed to check for them.

Comment: When you don't follow a (good) tutorial "to a T", you stand at getting errors. The official manuals are there to help you understand the syntax.

Comment: `('?,'?','?','?','?','?','?','?')` that's another syntax error. Where did you get that from? Not from the tutorial, I can say that. Your code contains too many errors.

Comment: @AmrAly You'll learn the language but you'll have the support of a framework. Writing PHP from scratch is really, really hard. There's a hundred things you need to be aware of, Fred's pointing out a bunch here, and those lessons can be painful and expensive. A framework has your back, it'll show you the best way to do things and give you a head-start on your learning: By showing good examples you can build on.

Comment: well seeing no life from you (the OP), either you left the question or you don't know what to do with all these comments or the answer below. I've shown you where most of your errors are, I didn't debug your entire code. You've an answer below. If it solved the question, accept it. If it didn't, tell them about it. Good luck.

Comment: @tadman I got your point.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in this line

```
    if ($stmt = $dbcon->prepare("UPDATE class SET ModuleCode = ?, Type = ?, Room = ?, StartTime = ?, EndTime = ?, DayOfWeek = ?, StartDate = ?, EndDate = ?
    WHERE ClassID=?"))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$cid, $modulecode, $type, $type, $room, $starttime, $endtime, $dow, $startdate, $enddate);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
```

number of type variable didnt match number of variables and also no need to put apostrophe around ? mark

```
    if ($stmt = $dbcon->prepare("UPDATE class SET ModuleCode = ?, Type = ?, Room = ?, StartTime = ?, EndTime = ?, DayOfWeek = ?, StartDate = ?, EndDate = ?
    WHERE ClassID=?"))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssissssss",$cid, $modulecode,  $type, $room, $starttime, $endtime, $dow, $startdate, $enddate);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
```

and also the following code

```
    if ($stmt = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO class(ModuleCode,Type,Room,StartTime,EndTime,DayOfWeek,StartDate,EndDate)VALUES
                                          (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $modulecode, $type, $room, $starttime, $endtime, $dow, $startdate, $enddate);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }
```

should be

```
    if ($stmt = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO class(ModuleCode,Type,Room,StartTime,EndTime,DayOfWeek,StartDate,EndDate)VALUES
                                          (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))
    {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $modulecode, $type, $room, $starttime, $endtime, $dow, $startdate, $enddate);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    }
```

Comment: Is that correct to check for `$cid` at the top of the page and declare it at the end of it?

Comment: Thanks @vSugumar for the help. I have applied your recommended changes and declared $cid at the top of the page (code updated above).
When I select to edit a row, the $cid is passed and displayed, but no other fields are passed. And when the I enter valid data and hit submit, I have the error " Undefined index: cid" for the line "if (is_numeric($_POST['cid']))"

Answer (score 0):

One thing i have noticed in your code That you check for a variable that haven't been yet declared which is `$cid` try to grab the variable first and then check for it :

```
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
```

then check you can :

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['cid'] && is_numeric($_GET['cid']))
```

try to add this code at the top of your edit page to grasp your `id` before doing anything else so if something went wrong you can redirect the user to another page.